# android studio build failed because of AAPT2

Tags: android-studio, cocos2d-x

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':ScrewAndBoltsPuzzle:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Errors occur when building on Android Studio, can anyone help me to solve it

i'm trying to disable AAPT2 by using 'android.enableAapt2=false' but it show me new error
A problem occurred evaluating project ':libcocos2dx'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated.
> The current default is 'true'.
> It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
> This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.